# How does the 't Hooft renormalization scheme work?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

I recently [learned](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4684-0991-8_17) there is a trick called t' Hooft transformation that allows us to define a new coupling constant $g_R$ from the usual one $g$ in such a way that the beta function for $g_R$ is two-loop exact. In other words, the beta function has no terms higher than $g_R^2$.

I'm confused about how this comes about and what it implies.

We start with

$$ \beta(g) = \sum a_n g^n .$$
Then, we define $g_R \equiv g + \sum r_n g^n$ such that

$$ \beta_R(g_R) = a_1 g_R + a_2 g_R^2. $$

**How does this work, i.e. why aren't there terms $\propto g_R^3,g_R^4,\ldots $ in $\beta_R(g_R)$?**

I found the following statements, but wasn't really able to understand what is going on:

> "The nullification of higher order coefficients of the β-function is achieved by finite renormalizations of charge." ([Source](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.5909.pdf))
>
> "t Hooft' has suggested that one can exploit this freedom in the choice of $g$ even further and choose a new coupling parameter $g_R$ such that the corresponding $\beta_R(g_R) = a_1 g_R + a_2 g_R^2$ (for the above case) and thus contains only two terms in its expansion in $g_R$."([Source](https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.20.881))
>
> "The 't Hooft transformation is based on the observation that the first two terms in the perturbation series for $\beta$ are scheme independent. These terms are therefore invariant under a certain class of transformations on the renormalized coupling parameter $g$, a class that includes the 't Hooft transformation in which P is exactly reduced to these two terms." ([Source](https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.29.253))

PS: In addition, to my confusion how this really works, I am confused about what it implies, e.g. for the radius of convergence of the perturbation series. See [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/337949/is-there-a-contradiction-between-the-t-hooft-transformation-and-a-zero-radius-o).

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.